# nicematrix: How to avoid the automatic numbering of first row?

Tags: nicematrix

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{NiceTabular}{>{\arabic{iRow}}cc>{\alph{iRow}}cc}[first-row]
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{}\Block{1-2}{Name} && \Block{1-2}{Country} & \\
    & George && France \\
    & John && Hellas \\
    & Paul && England \\
    & Nick && USA \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Questions

1. Is my code ok?
2. Is there a better code? (with nicematrix and without `\multicolumn` and first-row)

Comment: How is the question in the title related to the code and image given?

Comment: @daleif, the code is my answer to the question but I would like an answer without the use of `\multicolumn` and first-row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second `NiceTabular` reproduces the first without using `\multicolumn` or `first-row`.

[image: a]

`\NRow` will output the row number decremented by 1 from the second row forward. `\ARow` does the same with  alphabetical output.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix} 

\begin{document}
\begin{NiceTabular}{>{\arabic{iRow}}cc>{\alph{iRow}}cc}[first-row]
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{}\Block{1-2}{Name}   && \Block{1-2}{Country} & \\
                                & George    && France \\
                                & John      && Hellas \\
                                & Paul      && England \\
                                & Nick      && USA \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\bigskip

% *************************************************** added <<<<<
\newcounter{iRowtmp}
\newcommand{\NRow}{\ifnum\value{iRow} >1 \the\numexpr\value{iRow}-1\fi}     
\newcommand{\ARow}{\ifnum\value{iRow} >1 \setcounter{iRowtmp}{\the\numexpr\value{iRow}-1} \alph{iRowtmp}\fi}        


\begin{NiceTabular}{>{\NRow}cc>{\ARow}cc}
\Block{1-2}{Name}   &       & \Block{1-2}{Country}  & \\
                    & George&                       & France \\
                    & John  &                       & Hellas \\
                    & Paul  &                       & England \\
                    & Nick  &                       & USA \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

**Interesting bit** (after  @Alan Munn comment) : the `\ARow` command can be further simplified by suppressing the row number check as in

```
\newcommand{\ARow}{\setcounter{iRowtmp}{\the\numexpr\value{iRow}-1}\space\alph{iRowtmp}}
```

It will still work on the first row (where `\iRow-1=0`} because `\space\alph{<\iRow-1>}` will produce only the white space.

Comment: This can be made much more simple: your `\Nrow` macro should be `ifnum\value{iRow}=0\else\arabic{iRow}\fi` and this is only needed in the first column, i.e., you don't need your `\Arow` macro at all, not clear why, though :)

Comment: Thank for your feedback! The `\ARow` is needed to output the third column in alph format. Both `\NRow` and `\ARow` decreases `\iRow` by 1.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant to say is that you don't need the conditional code in your `\Arow` macro; you still need it to format the counter. But you don't need to do any arithmetic on the counter at all with the code I suggested as long as you have the `[first row]` option specified.

Comment: @Simon Dispa Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 4):

Simplifying Simon's answer, you can simply add a conditional to the first column row code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{NiceTabular}{>{\ifnum\value{iRow}=0\else\arabic{iRow}\fi}cc>{\alph{iRow}}cc}[first-row]
    & Name&& Country\\
    & George && France \\
    & John && Hellas \\
    & Paul && England \\
    & Nick && USA \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

It's actually not clear to me why the conditional code is only required in the one of the column specifications (it doesn't matter whether it's in the first or second column specification; either way it will suppress the counter in that row for all columns).

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.